# Как не переходить на другую HTML-страницу ?

Tags: html, запрос, методы

Как не переходить на другую страницу при использовании HTML-форм с методом action:

```
<form  method="post" action="http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/">
POST:
<input type="text" name="method" value="getQuote">
<input type="text" name="key" value="457653">
<input type="text" name="format"  value="text">
<input type="text" name="lang"  value="en">
<input type="submit" name="sub">
</form>
```

Comment: зачем плодить кучу почти однотипных вопросов если можно все задать в одном ?

[тут][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/74517/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

присваиваем форме и полям уникальные `id`.

меняем `submit` на `button` с указанным `onclick="doAjax()"`.

Где `doAjax()` - функция, выполняющая запрос на `document.getElementsById('form_id').action` и обрабатывающая полученный результат.

Comment: Почему-то не работает =)

Comment: занимательно... сервер возвращает `200 OK`, но содержимое страницы в колбэк не попадает... я заинтригован ) сейчас попробую немного с другой стороны подойти

Comment: Да все, ладно. Я уже разобрался. Спасибо большое =)

Comment: Мое решение - использовать свой промежуточный php файл(так себе решение). 

А Вы как решили проблему?

Answer (score 3):

Наверное, использовать Ajax..

Answer (score 2):

Отправлять форму в iframe. Только важно, чтобы action был на том же домене, иначе Same Origin Policy не даст прочитать ответ сервера из этого фрейма, тогда придётся прибегать к ухищрениям (ключевые слова для гугления: window.name-транспорт, location.hash-транспорт)